# Using variable in the jquery loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a function to execute after the modal shows up, but I need to send the table, dropdown id, value and name that I want to load in that dropdown, so far my code looks like:

```
$('#formModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    loadingDropdown("company", "id_company", "id_company", "name_company");
});

function loadingDropdown(table, id_dropdown, value, name){
    var $select = $("#"+id_dropdown+"");
    $.getJSON('./include/load.php?table='+table, function (data) {
        $select.html('');
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {                                
            $select.append('<option value="' + val.value+ '">' + val.name + '</option>');
        });
    });
}
```

My doubt is if I can use the variable that I am sending (`id_company` and `name_company`) to the `function (value, name)` and use in the `$.each` loop (`val.value` - `val.name`).

Thank you.

P.S.: I want to use the function for multiples dropdowns and because this I need to send the value and name always to know what value I need to get from the JSON result.

Since I am not inserting the "value" and "name" in the right way it brings "undefined".

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this and it didn't work or are you asking will it work? It should be easy enough to test this by referencing the variables in the `$.each` loop and then checking the console for errors...

Comment: Well, the code looks OK. What are the errors you are getting in your browser's console? Can you paste it over here in your Question?

Comment: Hi War10ck, It didn't work. I would like to see the best way to send the field name to the each loop.

Comment: Did you receive an error? If so, can you post it for us...

Comment: After the loading it will bring "undefined" because it is not getting the value and name in the each loop (val.value - val.name) and my doubt is how to user those two variable that I am sending in the function. It loads the number of lines but without the value / name for the dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

I just need to set:

```
val[value] and val[name]
```

Now I can use the same function to any dropdown. Case closed.